# Running different Hasura apps with one Postgres

Tags: hasura, hasura-docker

I have two different applications Build with Hasura as the backend and I would like both of them to use the same Postgres instance. Would I encounter any difficulties making this happen? Is it even possible? And what do I need to take into account while running my apps this way?

Both apps have different code bases, use different tables and are run from diffferent docker images.

Answer (score 0):

Different Hasura apps can be configured to use the same backend. It's possible. For postgres its simply multiple clients trying to access data. Since you said they use different tables, it makes things simpler.

Comment: Do I need to do anything to make sure there are no collision with the internal metadata Hasura uses to track migrations, events etc?

Comment: You might need to apply migrations and metadata from common repository. Metadata should include both the app's tables.